# Ubuntu16.04 install git failed

Tags: git, ubuntu-16.04

I used the fellow order to install git on my ubuntu16.04,but meet 
the problem. 
[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried with -f flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this PPA to your system
This will solve the issue.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! My problem is solved!

Comment: @Tom pleasure to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

May be something help you

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext unzip

wget https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.8.1.zip -O git.zip

unzip git.zip
cd git-*

make prefix=/usr/local all
sudo make prefix=/usr/local install
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the problem is still not solved.

Comment: I update my answer.

Comment: My problem has been solved. But thank you for your attention!